# Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64'

Tags: kali-linux

i had tried this command :-

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

but nothing happened for

```
apt-get install dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

again same error

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64 
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64' 
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64'
```

Comment: That means that `linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64` doesn't exist (or isn't in any repo your system knows about).  Is that how kali linux names its headers packages?  Try `dpkg -l 'linux-headers*'` and install the appropriate headers package for your running kernel.  BTW, the `dkms` package should depend on a `linux-headers-$arch` package or similar, so you shouldn't need to specify a specific kernel header package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this issues before, and I fix it. I open All Settings, and choose Details. Click on for updates, and your system will check updates. After it, if the system tell to install the update just do it and reboot.

Comment: The reboot after upgrading my system solved this issue for me.